# Get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.JDBCDriver using gradle when trying to access a local database

Tags: sqlite, gradle, groovy

I've attached the heading for my build.gradle file as well as the Task I'm using in order to query the database. I'm trying to access a database, pull a specific version number from the database and then save it somewhere else.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.*   
import groovy.sql.Sql

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations 
{   
    sshAntTast    
    svnant
}

repositories 
{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies 
{    
    // Compiles commonlib (commonlib compiles Appcompat so erg will have access 
    // to appcompat through commonlib)

    compile project(':commonLib')

    // Project requires plugins and assistance to use the SCP function from Ant
    sshAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.1', 'jsch:jsch:0.1.29'
    // Acquires Sqlite and driver from Maven in order to compare databases
    testCompile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.7.2'
}

task updateDatabase (dependsOn: 'prepareDatabase', type:Zip) {
doFirst {
    def oldDb = 'jdbc:sqlite:/$databaseLoc/unzipped'
    def dbDriver = 'org.hsqldb.JDBCDriver'
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(oldDb, dbDriver)
    sql.row("select * from database_version"){
        println "\n\ndB Version = ${it.version}"
        }
    sql.close()
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':wiser:updateDatabase'.

  > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.JDBCDriver

when I try to execute gradle updateDatabase. I've also tried changing the driver around a using different packages but I keep getting the same error. I've also tried adding compiling the jar file in my classpath but nothing seems to work. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because at time of execution gradle does not have the hsql driver jar in its classpath.

You will need to use something like this in your gradle script

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      classpath files("somelibfolder/hsqldb.jar")
   }
}
```